# Getting status 200 but no response in body

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, xmlhttprequest

Here is my service call

```
<script>
function secureClicked() {
    var uname = document.getElementById('uname').value;
    var pwd = document.getElementById('pwd').value;
    var obj = new Object();
    obj.username = uname;
    obj.password = pwd;
    var userObj = JSON.stringify(obj);

    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "http://127.0.0.1:9923/login";
    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
            var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            document.write(json.accesstoken);
            onComplete(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    };

    xhr.send(userObj);
}
```

Here is my backend code

```
    module.exports = {

    login: function(req, res) {

        MongoClient.connect(mongoUrl, function (err, db) {

            if (err) {
                console.log('into error of mongo');
                res.status(400).json({
                    message: 'Connection to database failed !!',
                    error: err
                });
            }

            insertDocument(db, req.body, function (result) {
                console.log('into insert doc');
                res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                res.status(200).json({
                    access_token: result._id
                });
            });

        });

        var insertDocument = function (db, data, callback) {
            console.log('into insert doc function');
            console.log(data);
            var string = JSON.stringify(data);
            var objectValue = JSON.parse(string);
            var username = objectValue['username'];
            var password = objectValue['password'];
            console.log(username);
            db.collection('user_list').findOne({$and:[{ 'username':username},{'password':password}]}, function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    res.status(500).json({
                        message: 'Failed to add in DB!!'
                    });
                } else {
                    callback(result);
                }
            });
        }
    }
};
```

I'm able to get response in postman, but unable to get response in browser.
Am I doing anything worng here ?
Can anyone help me on this?
Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Are you getting a CORS error in your browser devtools console? Unless your frontend code is also being served from `http://127.0.0.1:9923` then you’re sending the request cross-origin, so minimally the `http://127.0.0.1:9923/login` route in your backend must be configured to send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header. If your backend doesn’t do that, your browser will still receive the response (and you’ll be able to see it in your browser devtools) but your browser will refuse to allow your frontend code to access the response.

Comment: Your frontend code is also sending a `Content-Type` request header with the value `application/json;charset=UTF-8`, which triggers a CORS preflight OPTIONS request, so your backend must also be configured to respond to that OPTIONS request by sending `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` response headers. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests

Comment: @sideshowbarkerMy backed end has `app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
    next();
});`' enabled

Comment: Again, what error messages if any are you seeing in the browser devtools console?

Comment: no error messages

Comment: `res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With")` is not adequate, for the reason I mentioned above: It needs to also include `Content-Type`

Comment: I'm also including `res.contentType('application/json');` to my response

Comment: Can you access the response in devtools from the Network tab?

Comment: no, response is blank in network tab

Comment: OK yeah if the response is blank in the devtools Network tab and you’re not seeing any error messages in the devtools console, then it’s definitely not a CORS config problem and it’s either some backend failure or your XHR request is not actually sending the same request you’re sending with Postman.